# How can I add a custom 404 page on Vercel using vanilla Javscript?

Tags: javascript, vercel, custom-error-pages

I am not using any framework and I would like  to add a custom 404 page. In Vercel's documentation, they only provide information for users of frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [Custom 404 Page - Static Site Generator (SSG)](https://vercel.com/guides/custom-404-page#static-site-generator-ssg)

> Emit a `404.html` file to your Output Directory and it will be served as the 404 page when a route does not match any other static file.

**TL;DR** create a `404.html` file in the root of your site and Vercel will use that to serve requests that don't match any resources.

---

A static site generator like Hugo creates plain old HTML pages that (typically) *don't* operate as a Single-Page Application (SPA); there's an HTML file for each page.

This is just like a regular, non-framework, non-SPA website which matches your application structure.